# Msbuild task with variables

Tags: msbuild, msbuild-task

I want the $(fooAssemblyInfo.Version) to work in my BuildRepositoryZip task but it aint. Why? Do I have to move out the ItemName or something out of Target assemblyversion and in that case how is that done?

```
<Target Name="AssemblyVersion">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="..\Tools\Utility.dll">
        <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="fooAssemblyInfo"/>
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <Message Text="%(fooAssemblyInfo.Version)" />
</Target>




<!-- Zipping all *.zip to a package for repository server-->
<Target Name="BuildRepositoryZip" DependsOnTargets="AssemblyVersion">
            <!-- Create a zip file based on a Path -->
    <MSBuild.ExtensionPack.Compression.Zip TaskAction="Create" CompressPath="..\..\Deploy\*.zip" ZipFileName="..\..\$(fooAssemblyInfo.Version).zip"/>

</Target>
```

Comment: You have `%(foo` instead of `$(foo` in your pasted code.  Is that a mistake in your question or a mistake in your actual script?

Comment: It works by having % but the problem is not there. It is in the zip task

Build started 2012-10-15 11:09:16.
Project "C:\MC\xxx\Build\Build.proj" on node 1 (default targets).
AssemblyVersion:
  1.0.0.0
C:\MC\xxxx\Build\Build.proj(207,96): error MSB4184: The expression """.Vers
ion" cannot be evaluated. Method 'System.String.Version' not found.
Done Building Project "C:\MC\xxxxx\Build\Build.proj" (default targets) -- FA
ILED.

Comment: From that error it would seem that your variable `fooAssemblyInfo` is a string, not an `AssemblyInfo`.  How are you setting its value?

Comment: well in the assembly version task it gets the assembly nr from my assembly. That is seen because the message text tis writing out it ok. Then I want to use this nr to save my zip file with it. That is where it fails

Comment: I have found the error but dont know how to solve it.

It reads the 1.0.0.0 version number and at the end there is a /r character. How do I get delete that?